# Device with android 4.0 cannot start

Tags: android

I'm new in this forum.
My device cannot start. I installed android-sdk and found this using Logcat:

```
W/Zygote  (  257): Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
W/dalvikvm(  257): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Landroid/media/CameraProfile;
E/Zygote  (  257): Error preloading android.media.CameraProfile.
E/Zygote  (  257): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/Zygote  (  257):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadClasses(ZygoteInit.java:285)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:232)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:520)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/Zygote  (  257): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   257 could not load needed library 'libstagefright.so' for 'libmedia_jni.so' (reloc_library[1285]:   257 cannot locate '_ZN7logging10LogMessageC1EPKcii'...
E/Zygote  (  257): )
E/Zygote  (  257):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:391)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/Zygote  (  257):  at android.media.CameraProfile.<clinit>(CameraProfile.java:92)
E/Zygote  (  257):  ... 7 more
D/AndroidRuntime(  257): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a611f8)
I/Netd    (  266): Netd 1.0 starting
E/Netd    (  266): Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
E/Netd    (  266): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
```

Both mentioned libraries (libmedia_jni.so and libstagefright.so) are in /system/lib.
I also tried start it up using volume keys but no change.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried ? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser or the Android specific site, if such a site exists (I am not sure ^^)

Comment: This should be on [android.se], not here. Don't re-post it there, I've flagged it for the moderators, they'll move it.